# How do I make a translation animation in python?

Tags: python, animation, python-3.x, trigonometry

I'm trying to animate smooth motion between two points on the screen. At the moment, I am using the following python generator function to determine the point at which to draw the image:

```
#indexes (just for readability)
X=0
Y=1

def followLine(pointA, pointB, speed):
    x1, y1 = pointA
    x2, y2 = pointB
    movement=[0, 0]
    pos=list(pointA)
    diffY=y2-y1
    diffX=x2-x1
    if abs(diffY) > abs(diffX):
        #Y distance is greater than x distace
        movement[Y]=speed
        numFrames=abs(diffY)//speed
        if numFrames==0:
            movement[X]=0
        else:
            movement[X]=abs(diffX)//numFrames
    elif abs(diffY) < abs(diffX):
        #Y distance is less than x distace
        movement[X]=speed
        numFrames=abs(diffX)//speed
        if numFrames==0:
            movement[Y]=0
        else:
            movement[Y]=abs(diffY)//numFrames
    else: #Equal
        movement=[speed]*2

    if diffY < 0:
        #is negative
        movement[Y] *= -1
    if diffX < 0:
        movement[X] *= -1

    yield pointA
    while (abs(pos[X]-x2) > speed)or(abs(pos[Y]-y2) > speed):
        pos[X] += movement[X]
        pos[Y] += movement[Y]
        yield pos
    yield pointB
```

However, this has 2 problems:

- First, my main concern is that if `pointA` and `pointB` are very far apart, or if the speed is too low, the animation will pass right by `pointB`, and will keep going for infinity;
- The other problem is that, at the end of the animation, there is a sort of jolt as the image snaps into place. This jolt is usually fairly imperceptible, but I'd like to try and make the animation smoother.

How can I do this? I've been looking into the use of trig functions and that seems promising, but I'm not much of a math person, so I'm having trouble understanding exactly how I might implement it using trig.

Also, for what it's worth I'm using Python 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's missing information, I think.  Seems like you need to either substitute a `numFrames` arg for `speed`, or add a `time` arg in addition to `speed`.  Assuming the former, how about this. Note this generates numFrames+1 points so that pointA and pointB are always the first and last point, respectively, but that's trivial to change if that's not the behavior you want:

```
def followLine(pointA, pointB, numFrames):
    x1, y1 = pointA
    x2, y2 = pointB
    diffY = float(y2 - y1) /    numFrames
    diffX = float(x2 - x1) /    numFrames

    yield(pointA)
    for f in range(1,numFrames):
    point = (x1 + f * diffX, y1 + f * diffY)
        yield(point)
    yield(pointB)

points = followLine((0,0), (1,1), 10)

# then iterate over the points and do whatever                                                                                                
for p in points:
    print str(p)
```

Comment: Time is actually managed by another part of the program which calls `next()` on the generator once per frame, and `speed` was meant to be more along the lines of distance traveled per frame. But thanks, you got me going on the right track. I changed the arg back to speed and calculated `numFrames` with `int(max((abs(y2-y1), abs(x2-x1)))/speed`, and rounded the output (As I needed it in `int` form),  indented the first line of thar `for` loop, and it worked beautifully.